# Active model sending validation error twice during rack test.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

I have a simple restful rails api set up to feed json responses, I have a model line.rb where i have following validations.

```
validates :title, :presence => true, :length => {:minimum => 3, :maximum => 40},
:appropriate_title => {:message => "cannot have . and /"}
validates :department, :presence => true
validates :owner, :presence => true
validates :account, :presence => true
validate  :unique_inputs
validates :title, :uniqueness => { 
  :scope => :account, 
  :message => 'is already taken for this account', 
  :case_sensitive => false }
```

In my spec i have following suite

```
 it "with invalid attributes" do
 post"#{url}/#{account.name}.json", :api_key => application.key, :line => {:department => "Survey"}
 --some assertions --
 body = JSON.parse(last_response.body)
 body.should eql({"error"=>{"message"=>"[\"Title can't be blank\", \"Title is too short (minimum is 3 characters)\",]"}})
 end
```

As you can see since i am not supplying the title to the line it should have triggered the validation error and satisfied my assertion, However i am getting the same validation error twice.

```
  {"error"=>{
    "message"=>"[\"Title can't be blank\", \"Title is too short (minimum is 3 characters)\", \"Title can't be blank\", \"Title is too short (minimum is 3 characters)\"]"
    }}
```

This is really weird as in development mode i do not get this validation error twice. If you doubt i'm doing something wrong in my controller, following is what i have in my controller

```
@line = @current_user.lines.new(params[:line])
if @line.save
  respond_with(@line)
else
  render :json => {:error => {:message => @line.errors.full_messages}}
end
```

I can't figure out if it is the bug with the rack test or am i doing something wrong.

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem, except I get them even in dev-mode (I actually haven't even tried prod-mode - yet). My case was simpler:
 `validates :date, :presence => true, :uniqueness => { :scope => :artist_id }` 
 `validates :artist_id, :presence => true` 
My model only has a date and a description, as well as a relation to an artist (belongs_to). The uniqueness validation works fine, whereas the presence validation gives me double validation errors when I pass a blank value into the date field.

Did you ever resolve this problem? I am btw on rails 3.0.4.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
validates :department, :presence => true
validates :owner, :presence => true
validates :account, :presence => true
validate  :unique_inputs
validates :title, :presence => true, 
                  :length => {:minimum => 3, :maximum => 40},
                  :appropriate_title => {:message => "cannot have . and /"},
                  :uniqueness => { 
                    :scope => :account, 
                    :message => 'is already taken for this account', 
                    :case_sensitive => false }
```

Comment: Yes i did tried that but it didn't solved the problem at hand. The wierd thing is that the problem doen't appear when i don't scope the creation, but gives double validation error when i am scoping it  `@line = @current_user.lines.new(params[:line])`

Answer (score 0):

Do you have some associations that could result in double validation?

You could try adding `validate => false` e.g.

```
has_one :account, :validate => false
```

I'm not totally sure why this happens but sometimes the associations result in running validations twice in the same object. You can try to test it also in the console by having

```
l = User.last.lines.new(); l.valid?; l.errors
# might return in double errors
l = Line.new(); l.valid?; l.errors
# errors probably just once
```